# jQuery Keyboard Shortcuts Chrome issue

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to have a button that can use keyboard shortcuts. With the button below I would like to be able to push "ALT + R" to use the button. This is working in IE and Firefox but for some reason I am unable to get the button to work in chrome? Does anyone have any workarounds for chrome as well? Did they disable the alt button or something...

http://jsfiddle.net/qx62t4zd/3/

```js
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.altKey==true && event.key=="r"){
        alert("Works");
     }
    });
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="Report">REPORT</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `keydown`, you should check `event.keyCode`

Within (my version of) Chrome, `event.key` is always null for the keydown - so it's not specific to <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, but to all keys.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.altKey==true && event.keyCode==82){
            alert("Works");
        }
    });
```

where `82` is the <kbd>R</kbd> key

---

However, according to the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown), this is deprecated, and you should use `key` instead but also that `key` is unimplemented due to a bug...

You should be ok with `.keyCode` for a few years yet.